# boton "next" en fullCalendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

Estoy intentando hacer que FullCalendar solo me muestre el mes actual y los dos siguientes, ya que tiene una estructura para buscar fechas en esos tres meses. Estoy utilizando la app de LibreBooking. Lo que se me ocurrió es solo desactivar el botón "next", pero no logro encontrar el archivo que controla ese calendario. ¿Alguien tiene algún consejo?

Desde ya, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. En [es.so] no damos consejos o sugerencias, aquí resolvemos problemas específicos, que se puedan reproducir. Tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Saludos